# How best create a game map in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

I'm looking for some idea's on how to create the 2d layout (walk path) of a game.
The tiles will be 32x32 pixels aswell as the character moving on the tiles.

I've thought of two ways currently, havn't tried any of them out yet.

The game will be shown in a window of about 400x300 or 512x356 something.. not much bigger than that where the game map itself could be bigger then 1000x1000. So only a portion of the map will be visible most times.

So here's my 2 options as far as I've thought of them.

**[1]:** Create the entire map at the start (which might increase the loading times but it will make it more easy to move the map around) including each object, player, enemies etc etc.

**[2]:** Create only the map seen and 1 tile around it (which is not visible) so I can make that one visible with a story board and remove the row / column which is out of bounds and create a column again.

Which means, If I have a room of 5x5 tiles, and I load 7x7 tiles. If I move right, I move all the tiles left and keep the player in the middle of the screen. Then I remove the far left set of tiles and create a new set of tiles on the right side, which will hopefully be done before the storyboard has finished moving.

In the second method all I have to consider is objects that are larger then 32x32. How could I best react on those.. However, this is a problem I'd like to address later.. Right now I prefer to know people's opinions and possible better methods.

I do apoligize if this question is no apropriate for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just be careful with the "load" word. Loading, means taking the data from the disk/drive and putting it memory. For that, you should load all the current world/map at once, before the game start. Trust me, you don't want to get yourself in dynamic loading stuff while the map is running.

But you only need to load the definition of your map, you don't need to create the instance of the object at that point. So you can create the instance from the map definition as the player walks... but are you really that constraint in memory? I can understand that for a game like Minecraft or Terraria where the map contains virtually millions of tiles... But for 32x32, you can consider making them all when you load the definition.

Of course, whatever the solution, you should only draw/compute/collide/update the tiles that are visible on screen.

Comment: Ofcourse, what I ment is.. what is the best way to render the graphics to the player. Should I 'load' all the tiles in advance or should I 'load' them after each move..  should I use a canvas or a wrappanel,  should I use picture boxes or grids?

Comment: Like I said, "load" means taking data from the disk and putting it in memory. Why would you "load" stuff from the disk as the player move around? Do you want to "create" the instances of the tiles as you walk around? Like I said, for 32x32, it's probably overkilled.

Comment: So basicly I should create the tiles and load the pictures from disk at the game start and just show them in a canvas / picture box / whatever floats my boat...  It should not have down time if I go from one map to a complete other map ?

Comment: It will have down time. But how long do you think it would take to loop over 32x32 items? (1024 items) If you are creative, you can hide that time behind some screen effects.